# Binding value from another class

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have helper class and in this

```
UserModel _CurrentUser = new UserModel();
public UserModel CurrentUser
{
    get
    {
        return _CurrentUser;
    }
    set
    {
        if(Equals(value,_CurrentUser))
        {
            return;
        }
        _CurrentUser = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("CurrentUser");
        UserDataAccessor.UpdateUserLoginTime(_CurrentUser);
    }
}
```

In MainWindow.xaml

```
xmlns:helper="clr-namespace:TMSV2.Helper"
```

and i want to show `Name` property of `CurrentUser` in `TextBlock` of `mainwidow`.

```
<TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Margin="0,40,30,40"
           Text="How can i write here"/>
```

How can I show this value in `Mainwindow`?

**Update**

my user model is

```
public class UserModel:BaseModel
    {
        string _Name;
        public string Name
        {
            get
            {
                return _Name;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_Name != value)
                {
                    _Name = value;
                    RaisePropertyChange("Name");
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Margin="0,40,30,40"
           Text="{Binding CurrentUser.Name}"/> Does not work?

Comment: @PéterHidvégi Thank for your answer, it's not work.

Comment: Can you write here your Name property structure pls?

Comment: @PéterHidvégi i was updated my question.

Comment: What is UserDataAccessor.UpdateUserLoginTime(_CurrentUser) doing? if it's modify your value then you should call your RaisePropertyChanged("CurrentUser") after UserDataAccessor. Did you set your DataContext?

Comment: Where is your "public UserModel CurrentUser" property? Is it in the mainWindow.xaml.cs or another (real view model) .cs? if it is in your mainWindow.xaml.cs pls make sure you have "DataContext = this;" in your contructor.

Comment: "CurrentUser"  property is in another class and i am not sure it is cause because of not static property? Because "CurrentUser" property is not static  property.

Comment: Nope. Property have to be part of your instance and public. Did you set your View(Window) DataContext somewhere? DataContext have to be that instance (ViewModel class) which has CurrentUser property. (Your Window has got a DataContext property. This property must have be set to your view model instance.)

Comment: Yep i already add "DataContext=this;" but "CurrentUser" property not include in "this" because "CurrentUser" property is in another class(Helper).

Comment: "DataContext=this" is wrong if your view model is NOT your xaml.cs. So you have to set your DataContext. DataContext = new yourHelperClass() , which contains CurrentUser.

Comment: I think i have two DataContext (ViewModel and HelperClass) that why "DataContext=this" not solved.Normally i use property of ViewModel and now i want to also use property of "HelperClass".If i add "DataContext=MyHelperClass",this will disable property of viewmodel.

Comment: Your ViewModel equals YourHelperClass. Pls forget DataContext = this in this way. Just set DataContext = YourHelperClass.

Comment: Thanks for you patient, It is work for "CurrentUser" but property of "viewmodel" are not working.

Comment: Ohh I just little updated my viewmodel .i add new property to viewmodel and this property return "CurrentUser" property of helper. So DataContext=this will work and  i can call "Name" of new property.

Comment: Where are you set your Name property? Do you invoke PropertyChanged after Name has been modified?

Comment: I am not sure about modified but "CurrentUser" are set only one times when user login and all are initialize after user log out. So i think my updated "viewmodel" will cover this process but i am not tested.I will let you known after i tested.Thank you for your comment.

Comment: Just set one time your DataContext (=YourHelperViewModelInstance) and you have to invoke PropertyChange after you set or modify Name because View will not be updated.